# Can't collate all the files sent to s3 in a batch

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, file-upload, amazon-s3

I have a React + Rails chat application and I want to add attachments to the same.

I'm using [React Dropzone component](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/React-Dropzone-Component) to do attach images. Every time an image successfully gets added to the dropzone, it calls the `attachToS3` function and posts that image to S3 as well. On successful posting it sets the state of `new_message_content` as the url of the file.
Once, the user has uploaded all the files, they can click on `send` which inserts the `new_message_content` as a new message in the conversation.

Since, I'm allowing users to add multiple files at the same time therefore my state only contains the url of the last uploaded file and not an array of all the URL's.

My `dropzone` is being rendered as follows:

```
renderFileDropzone() {
let componentConfig = { postUrl: 'random_url'},
            djsConfig = { autoProcessQueue: true, addRemoveLinks: true },
            eventHandlers = { addedfile: this.attachToS3.bind(this) };
    return(
            <div>
                <div className="dashboard-modal">
                    <div className="dashboard-modal-content">
                        <div className="dashboard-modal-header">
                            <h5>Send files to {this.state.counterparty.name}</h5>
                            <span onClick={this.closeDropzone.bind(this)} className="icon-cancel modal-close"></span>
                        </div>
                        <form>
                            <div className="dashboard-modal-body">
                                <DropzoneComponent config={componentConfig} eventHandlers = {eventHandlers} djsConfig = {djsConfig} />
                                <button onClick={this.sendMessage.bind(this)} type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary">Send Files</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="modal-bg bg-transparent-black"></div>
            </div>
    )
}
```

Now, my Dropzone component allows multiple file uploads at the same time but since I can't do a direct upload to Amazon S3 of multiple files at the same time so I pass the files, one by one.

`attachToS3 function`

```
attachToS3(file) {
    let self = this;
    API.get('user/s3_post_attachment', {filename : file.name}, function (s3_params) {
        let formData = new FormData();
        Object.keys(s3_params.formdata).forEach(function(k) {
            formData.append(k, s3_params.formdata[k]);
        });
        formData.append('file', file);
        $.ajax({
                    url: s3_params.url,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    async: true,
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function (data) {
                        let file_url = $(data).find('Location').html();
                        self.setState({ new_message_content : file_url });
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false
        });
    });
}
```

I tried adding a `localStorage` to my `attachToS3` function, like this:

```
var url_array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('allFiles'));
if (url_array == null) url_array = [];
var url = {
  'url' : file_url
};
localStorage.setItem('url', JSON.stringify(url));
url_array.push(url);
localStorage.setItem('allURL', JSON.stringify(url_array));
```

But it's not working and I'm getting an error `url_array.push` is not a function.

Is there any way to get all the file url's in an array?